# How to specify Oracle SID to connectionStrings in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, web-config

I have an ASP.NET application whose connection to the database seems to fail to open because of the Oracle SID not being specified. I can't find any doc on how to specify it in the connection string. Did anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample :

```
         <connectionStrings>
            <add name="{ConnectionName}" 
            connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;" 
            providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
         </connectionStrings>
```

After adding the connection string to the web config you can use

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

To retrieve the connection string